# Hangfired BackgroundJob.Enqueue not logging to Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog, hangfire

My .NET Core application is logging fine normally. When I kick off a job to run in the background using hangfire. The method that is called does not log anything.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Then my code

```
      Log.Fatal("This works");
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Example());
```

Does not work

```
public async Task Example()
{
  Log.Fatal("Does not work");
}
```

Comment: Where does ` builder.AddSerilog();` come from? Are you using some sort of integration library? Please mention that, and what version it is. May be a good idea to include your Serilog configuration as well.

Comment: I have changed my adding serilog to what I originally had setting it up in Program.cs.

Comment: Again: you need to mention what packages you're using for this, and what versions.